# Views: how to display different buttons before/after associated date?

Tags: datetime, views

I've got a node that has a deadline date field.  I am configuring a view that shows a list of all the nodes.

If we are past the deadline for a given node, I want to show "closed" text.  If not, I want to show a link that says "Apply".

I suspect that I may have to use views_php but I'm not sure exactly how to do this, and I also want to make sure there isn't another way to do it without the performance hit of views_php.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to do this kind of conditional logic:

1. Use the [views_php module](https://drupal.org/project/views_php)
2. Make a [views field template](http://www.flowbyte.com/journal/drupal-7-theming-views-field-templates)
3. Write a views widget (or formatter, or something - what is the correct terminology?)

I ended up taking a bit of a shortcut and going ahead with views_php for now.  I'm never going to be dealing with more than a few hundred rows, so I'm not to shaken up over the poor performance of views_php.

This module is pretty easy to use.  Add a "Global: PHP" field.  I found `dpm( $data )` and other variations to be very useful.

Comment: Really though, it's just as fast if not faster to put a global text field and override it with a field template. Better performance and no need for views PHP.